# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects from CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have an input which is WHOIS_Python.csv. It contains four IPs in one column, four rows.

I would run the following code:

```
import csv
import requests

API_URL = "http://ip-api.com/line/"

with open('WHOIS_Python.csv') as csvfile:
    IPReader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar='|' )
    for row in IPReader:
        res = requests.get(API_URL + ''.join(row) + "?fields=query,as")
        print(res.text)
```

This is the current results:

```
222.22.222.22


222.22.2.22


22.222.2.222


2.2.222.22
```

I've tested the API by running the following code:

```
import requests

IP = "74.125.68.100"
API_URL = "http://ip-api.com/json/"

res = requests.get(API_URL + IP + "?fields=query,as")
print(res.text)
```

I would receive the following results (this is the results I would like get):

```
AS15169 Google Inc.
74.125.68.100
```

Originally, I was getting "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects" but that's not the issue now. I would like to get the same results from when I tested the API.

Comment: What is `IP`? you don't show it

Comment: `row` is not in your `for` loop. Where is `IP` from?

Comment: My apologies, it's supposed to say: for row in IPReader:
        res = requests.get(API_URL + row + "?fields=query,as")
        print(res.text)

Comment: A multi-row CSV will return a nested list, with each sublist representing one row. I.e. `IPReader = [[row_1], [row_2]]`. Try changing to `res = requests.get(API_URL + row[0] + "?fields=query,as")`

Comment: Thanks roganjosh. I tried your suggestion and it returned the list of IPs. I'm no longer receiving the error, but it only returned the list of IPs, but not the AS.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the AS"

Comment: I've updated the original post, hoping it provides more clarification of where I'm at. As for "AS", your right, I should have explained. "AS" is one of the returned values the API provides. You can see additional information here: http://ip-api.com/docs/api:returned_values

Comment: roganjosh, I double checked my code and realized that everything is functioning the way it's supposed to. The url was attempting to pull both the 'query' value as well as the 'as' value, but the four IPs didn't have an 'as' value. Something I overlooked. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Glad it's sorted :) I keep tabs open for questions I have commented on. If you had, instead, used '@' in front of my name, I would get a notification and I would see your comments; I just happened to be going through my tabs and saw this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row` is a list. You can't concatenate strings and lists in python. You have a few options.

1. Convert the strings to lists:

   `res = requests.get([API_URL] + row + ["?fields=query,as"])`
2. Convert the list to a string (*this is what you're more than likely looking for*):

   `res = requests.get(API_URL + ''.join(row) + "?fields=query,as")`

If the row is a list of lists, well then you can apply the above if needed, and/or subscripting the data you're looking for i.e. `row[0]`

Comment: Thank you mrdomoboto. I tried the second suggestion but it only returned the list of IPs. I'm no longer receiving the error, but it only returned the list of IPs and not the AS

Comment: It's difficult for any of us to try and help you if you don't show us what your data looks like. Please give us a clear input (data coming in i.e. the csv) to output (data after computation i.e. what `res` is) example. @LazyPanda

Comment: Understandable. I've updated the original post and I hope this provides  some clarity. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: mrdomoboto, I double checked my code and  realized that everything is functioning the way it's supposed to. The url was attempting to pull both the query value as well as the 'as' value, but the four IPs didn't have an 'as' value. Thank you so much for your help!!